# LinearLayout not clickable - Android

Tags: android, onclick, android-linearlayout

I know this is a question that has been asked before, but I think I'm doing the correct coding, and yet, I'm not coming up with the proper result. Here my xml code:

```
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/directions_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon_directions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                <TextView android:text="Directions"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

I don't know if this makes a difference or not, but the LinearLayout that is the parent of the one shown is not clickable.

Here is where I set the OnClickListener in the code:

```
    listener_layout = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }

    };
    call_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.call_layout);
    call_layout.setOnClickListener(listener_layout);
```

but it never get fired...Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

You didn't call `show()`on your toast, which seems like your listener doesn't fire.

The above line should be:

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Yeah, sometimes breakpoints look like more reliable approach)

Comment: @inazaruk: Can I +1,000 this?